# Looking up a value and putting a different value in a cell in the same row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

All the cells I reference can be found in the image below. I'm trying to figure out how to search for a name that I enter in F3 and then put the date I have in E3 into the corresponding cell in column C.

So, if I put Jim Jones in F3 and today's date in E3, that date would be entered into C3. I know `VLOOKUP()` and the `INDEX()` `MATCH()` pairing can find a cell based on a value, but I think my limited knowledge of Excel and its functions is making my Google searches unfruitful.

[image: Example]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If understood correctly, then only an `IF()` function would be suffice here.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C3</kbd>

```
=IF(B5=$E$3,$F$3,"")
```

---

The above formula needs to fill down!

---

However if you are in `MS365` then, spill it for the whole range.

```
=IF(B5:B10=E3,F3,"")
```

---

Format the cells as dates.